# ModuleNotFoundError when running script with conda from console (but not in jupyter) on remote machine

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I work on a remote desktop with limited access, which means I cannot install anything and I cannot use `pip` or `conda install` to install any packages (blocked by firewall). I do have a portable Python version and Miniconda "installed".

So I created a `conda environment` on my local machine and copied it to the remote desktop. Today I needed a `new_package` on the remote machine, so I installed it on my local machine and copied the package folders (`/new_package/` and `/new_package-0.0.1.dist-info/`)

from my local
`Python_installation/Lib/site-packages`

to my conda environment on the remote machine
`anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/site-packages/`

When I run `conda list` I can now find the copied package on the remote machine.

**Problem:**
However, when I try to run a python script with `conda run python myscript.py` with has an import statement to the `new_package`, it fails with `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(32): Subprocess for 'conda run ['python', '.\\myscript.py']' command failed.  (See above for error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\\mycsript.py", line 2, in <module>
    from new_package import something
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new_package'
```

However, when I start up a `jupyter notebook` with one line

```
from myscript.py import *
```

it imports everything and it executes flawlessly. So the problem is not that the package does not work - conda recongizes the packages with `conda list` and I can import it in `jupyter notebook`, but not when I run a script from the console.

What do I need to do, so I can execute the script from the console?

Comment: Have you tried to run your script as a module via the command line, i.e `python -m myscript`?

Comment: It shows the same error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new_package'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite some time I revisited the problem and found a solution - don't activate the environment, but pass the environment as a parameter to `conda run` as follows. For some reason this imports the modules correctly.

Does NOT work and fails on imports:

```
conda activate my_environment
conda run python my_file.py
```

Working solution:

```
conda run -n my_environment python my_file.py
```